# Typescript: How can I narrowing return type of a function?

Tags: typescript, narrowing

```js
type DequeNode<T> = {
  value: T;
  prev?: DequeNode<T>;
  next?: DequeNode<T>;
};

class Deque<T> {
  head?: DequeNode<T>;
  tail?: DequeNode<T>;
  size = 0;

  first() {
    return this.head?.value;
  }

  isEmpty() {
    return this.head == null
  }
}

const deque = new Deque<number>()
if (!deque.isEmpty()) {
  deque.first() // number | undefined
  deque.head?.value // number | undefined
}

if (deque.head) {
  deque.first() // number | undefined
  deque.head.value // number
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhCOBXCA5A9gEwgHgCoD4oBeKAbwCgooA3AQwBtkAuKXAbkqjACcJqB+FnCSpMOAhyoA7CAA9gg2AmTosefBwC+HcgGN6tAM6GlI9WU4ALCLQyLhKseslRgtAJb17y0WomdDdwAvaBIABh0qADN3bkNgAAoASgsqKl5gRG4pV0t3QwA6a1t+ArpGCBdNck58gFEAWzBQZNS0jKyc4DzC4oxiEilEenpOauq9NCl4qCwRYigZAHdTZGwhhoAjCG58ZPJ3KKgEgEI55AL6ppaklIoqc4gCmLjElIB6d8XELZ2oAB8oIgpFgYjIMJxHkUbHYygxkFBPt9ftwAUCQRAwRAIRNDscoX07pCfM9YvFWkiNttUYDgaD3ODiSJobY4RVEV8qTtyJogA)

In the above code, it can correctly infer type of `deque.head.value` if `deque.head` is not null. But it can't work when using `deque.first()`

How can I make `isEmpty()` check work and make `first()` return only type `number`?

Comment: Use `this.head == null || this.head == undefined;` for `isEmpty`

Comment: @RahulRoy, That's not reasonable advice since `== null` and `== undefined` are the same.  That also has no effect on the narrowing.

Comment: Class declarations cannot make union-typed instances, which is what you need.  You can use type assertions and other tricks to make it appear so, like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N7GQEN) shows, but I don't know that it's worth the trouble.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining (or find a suitable dupe target). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, your solution works! Can you explain more on why my code does not just work under the hood and why your code works? And also, if you were to implement this Deque structure in your codebase, would you go all the way like you did in the playground, or just use a non-null assertion when needed?

Comment: I've explained in my answer why yours doesn't work and why mine does.  As for what I would do, I'm not sure, it depends on the use case, which I don't have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way checking `deque.isEmpty()` would work to narrow the apparent type of `deque` is if it were a [user-defined type guard method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) with a return type of the form `this is ⋯`.  You could give a name to the type of a `Deque<T>` for which `isEmpty()` is `true`:

```
interface EmptyDeque<T> extends Deque<T> {
  head?: undefined;
  first(): undefined;
}
```

and then make `isEmpty()` a type guard method:

```
class Deque<T> {
  /* ✂ snip ✂ */
  isEmpty(): this is EmptyDeque<T> {
    return this.head == null
  }
}
```

But while this does what you want when you check `deque.isEmpty()` directly:

```
const deque = new Deque<number>()
if (deque.isEmpty()) {
  deque.first(); // undefined    
  deque.head; // undefined
}
```

It will not behave as expected when you check `!deque.isEmpty()`:

```
if (!deque.isEmpty()) {
  deque.first() // number | undefined
  deque.head?.value // number | undefined
}
```

And that's because TypeScript has no built-in mechanism to say that a `Deque<T>` which is *not* an `EmptyDeque<T>` has any special characteristics.  You'd like to say that when `isEmpty()` returns `false` that it narrows `Deque<T>` to a `NonEmptyDeque<T>` defined like

```
interface NonEmptyDeque<T> extends Deque<T> {
  head: DequeNode<T>;
  first(): T;
}
```

but there's no syntax for describing the `false` side of a type guard.  There's a longstanding feature request for it at [microsoft/TypeScript#15048](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15048), and if that is ever implemented maybe you could write

```
class Deque<T> {
  // ⚠ THIS IS NOT VALID TS, DON'T TRY THIS ⚠
  isEmpty(): this is EmptyDeque<T> else this is NonEmptyDeque {
    return this.head == null
  }
}
```

and everything would behave as you want.  But you can't do that, so we're stuck.

---

Ideally you'd like to say that a `Deque<T>` is either an `EmptyDeque<T>` or a `NonEmptyDeque<T>`, meaning that conceptually it is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) like

```
type Deque<T> = EmptyDeque<T> | NonEmptyDeque<T>;
```

If that were the case, then when you narrow a `Deque<T>` to prohibit `EmptyDeque<T>` with `!deque.isEmpty()`, then it would become a `NonEmptyDeque<T>` necessarily.

But [classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html) in TypeScript cannot be unions; or at least class *declarations* do not result in union-typed instances.  You can describe the type of the constructor like

```
const Deque: new<T>() => Deque<T> = class ⋯;
```

but any such assignment will confuse the compiler, since the class constructor expression on the righthand side will not be seen as constructing a union.  You'll need to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) like

```
const Deque = class ⋯ as new<T>() => Deque<T>;
```

and deal with the laxness in compiler verification by being very careful.

So all that gives us

```
interface BaseDeque<T> {
  isEmpty(): this is EmptyDeque<T>
  tail?: DequeNode<T>;
  size: number;
}
interface EmptyDeque<T> extends BaseDeque<T> {
  head?: undefined;    
  first(): undefined;
}
interface NonEmptyDeque<T> extends BaseDeque<T> {
  head: DequeNode<T>;
  first(): T;
}
type Deque<T> = EmptyDeque<T> | NonEmptyDeque<T>;
class _Deque<T> {
  head?: DequeNode<T>;
  tail?: DequeNode<T>;
  size = 0;   
  first() {
    return this.head?.value;
  }
  isEmpty(): this is EmptyDeque<T> {
    return this.head == null
  }
}
const Deque = _Deque as new <T>() => Deque<T>;
```

which we can now test:

```
const deque = new Deque<number>();
const x = deque.first(); // const x: number | undefined 
const y = deque.head?.value; // const y: number | undefined
if (!deque.isEmpty()) {
  const x = deque.first(); // const x: number
  const y = deque.head.value; // const y: number
} else {
  const x = deque.first(); // const x: undefined
  const y = deque.head; // undefined
}
```

This looks good and works as you want.  But is it worth it?

---

It really depends on your use case whether something like this is worthwhile.  Personally if I needed to distinguish between these two cases at the type level and still use classes, I'd just write a `BaseDeque<T>` class and then have `NonEmptyDeque<T>` and `EmptyDeque<T>` subclasses, and use the union type `Deque<T>` elsewhere.  This prevents the need for type assertions.  But if we're refactoring like this we might as well avoid classes entirely since you could get by with plain objects also.  The particular pros and cons of this are out of scope here, so I'll stop digressing.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhCOBXCA5A9gEwgHgCoD4oBeKAbwCgooA3AQwBtkAuKXAbkqjACcJqB+FnCSpMOAhyoA7CAA9gg2AmTosefBwC+HcuSm0AthADOYWgGNoAeW4BLAOZldnW1OARuAMwvQAogbBQYWR1KDl3KQxjJRFQiioqAAsIWgxFREiIT1cIDEkE7O5jYAAKAEoWDKxsmTzOTRc3D29LKHQpf0CQYPFCcIhI6J64ziSUjCFlUTUJUahC4vKWdnrOc3paYyGpkYSoZNTFHtVe-KpgWlt6I6mT9TOoY1sAL2gSAAYdPYXSsqc9qi8YCIbhSKDARK2YwAOgOaWhdEYEAeDTmUM6oCW4Mh0ShUAx3R2BH+AKBILBEKhsPGxBIUkQ9HocwaVFRVHMaCkxSgWBExCgMgA7jEQvSDAAjDz4couTxQEq85DQ9EBTFlP7xBKKiDQn7lNhQAD0hqgVSyOQwezm2upqQNxtNmRquVWVFscpKAEIbSquuUNdaprrbEVfkaTWLJdwoAAfR3VC2BkS2+GI5DhgWICUeWPx821Vao1zuLw+KAAIU2EGGxM1vrVLEpuOiBJr+E4FyuNxEd1mVCerxYkY8WnIxeaZdbRL68gGUQrVbbJLh6SdFq+8xDiwqeeddQa49LrXaU9ixP6gwXxmr0+X40mPbE904ep3KwaoEgIt6-NPIWJcYnqqhJnho5DrJs0QAPpLpqK4PioT59uClzXAh0ynJwA5vFAny6FQr4koCEDAqC2JUiuCIMMg+QslA9YgFiTb0S2wGwXMZJkU2Ka0pmjKFuBnLcj0-IwVMUCbAKEDCuo5TEIQbb2hGEC5OCaASVsHjAPsHgQLoHJctp2r8kK37YMO3DSmUHAGdysj8jar5KVAtnabIQ5ZlGuZmnuUCCYZUAgA5QaUWmyIZq5gUedm0Zxj5ibuvK3pBgx-okpF9kkI5W6-M5GXRVGaxCdpQVZSF4xUUieXFVFmYxeQmhhPQ17pTVmU8kGTkRW1lRrgW7I1aVHXJnCznxQWqJAA)